# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException -- my cursor is empty

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

So I have been trying to query in my sqlite database for my android app. However, it seems like my cursor is not working like it is supposed too as I can get any results.

I know that I only have 3 items in my database, but what I put in my query are valid attributes for my 3 items stored. But there is still no result.

Below is my code for the query function and my database model.

```
// To get data from DB by querying the items selected
    public String getData(int firstSelection, int secondSelection, int thirdSelection,
                          int fourthSelection, int fifthSelection)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String firstSelectionStr, secondSelectionStr, thirdSelectionStr, fourthSelectionStr, fifthSelectionStr;

        firstSelectionStr = Integer.toString(firstSelection);
        secondSelectionStr = Integer.toString(secondSelection);
        thirdSelectionStr = Integer.toString(thirdSelection);
        fourthSelectionStr = Integer.toString(fourthSelection);
        fifthSelectionStr = Integer.toString(fifthSelection);

        //String[] columns = {DBHelper.UID,DBHelper.CNAME};
        //Cursor cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM "+ DBHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DBHelper.FIRST_ATTRIBUTE + "=? "
                + " AND " + DBHelper.SECOND_ATTRIBUTE + "=? " + " AND " + DBHelper.THIRD_ATTRIBUTE + "=? " + " AND " + DBHelper.FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE + "=? "
                + " AND " + DBHelper.FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE + "=?";
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] {firstSelectionStr, secondSelectionStr, thirdSelectionStr,
                            fourthSelectionStr, fifthSelectionStr});
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor != null) {

            int tresult = cursor.getCount();

            // Append every data together
            do {
                //int cursorID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.UID));
                String chosenItem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CNAME));
                buffer.append(chosenItem + " ");
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        /*while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            //int cursorID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.UID));
            String chosenItem = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CNAME));
            buffer.append(chosenItem + " ");
        }*/
        }

        return buffer.toString();
    }

static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "CraftsAppDatabase.db";    // Database Name
        private static final String TABLE_NAME = "CraftTools";   // Table Name
        private static final String RESULT_TABLE = "Result";   // Table Name
        private static final int DATABASE_Version = 1;    // Database Version
        private static final String UID="_id";     // Column I (Primary Key)
        private static final String CNAME = "Craft_Name";    //Column II
        private static final String RESULT = "Result_Name";    //Column II
        private static final String FIRST_ATTRIBUTE = "First_Attribute";    //Column III
        private static final String SECOND_ATTRIBUTE = "Second_Attribute";    //Column IV
        private static final String THIRD_ATTRIBUTE = "Third_Attribute";    //Column V
        private static final String FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE = "Fourth_Attribute";    //Column VI
        private static final String FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE = "Fifth_Attribute";    //Column VII
        private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+
                " ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+CNAME+" VARCHAR(255)" +
                ", "+FIRST_ATTRIBUTE+" VARCHAR(255), "+SECOND_ATTRIBUTE+" VARCHAR(255)" +
                ", "+THIRD_ATTRIBUTE+" VARCHAR(255), "+FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE+" VARCHAR(255)" +
                ", "+FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE+" VARCHAR(255));";
        private static final String CREATE_OTHER_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+RESULT_TABLE+
                " ("+UID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+RESULT+" VARCHAR(255));";
        private static final String DROP_TABLE ="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+RESULT_TABLE;
        private Context context;

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_Version);
            this.context=context;
        }

        /*public void deleteTable(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db = getWritableDatabase();
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CraftTools");
        }*/

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_OTHER_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + "(Craft_Name, First_Attribute, Second_Attribute, Third_Attribute, Fourth_Attribute, Fifth_Attribute ) " +
                    "VALUES ('Landscape Drawing', '1', '4','8', '0', '0')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + "(Craft_Name, First_Attribute, Second_Attribute, Third_Attribute, Fourth_Attribute, Fifth_Attribute ) " +
                    "VALUES ('Popsicle Sticks House', '2', '3','0', '0', '0')");
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + "(Craft_Name, First_Attribute, Second_Attribute, Third_Attribute, Fourth_Attribute, Fifth_Attribute ) " +
                    "VALUES ('Sunset Painting', '4', '7','10', '0', '0')");

            /*try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Message.message(context,""+e);
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            //db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
            if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE CraftTools ADD COLUMN FIRST_ATTRIBUTE INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE CraftTools ADD COLUMN SECOND_ATTRIBUTE INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE CraftTools ADD COLUMN THIRD_ATTRIBUTE INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE CraftTools ADD COLUMN FOURTH_ATTRIBUTE INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
                db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE CraftTools ADD COLUMN FIFTH_ATTRIBUTE INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
            //onCreate(db);
            /*try {
                Message.message(context,"OnUpgrade");
                db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
                onCreate(db);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Message.message(context,""+e);*/
            }
        }


    }
```

My logcat for the error is below this line. I am not sure why my result is empty or why nothing is being put in the buffer.

```
11-27 22:43:28.898 4502-4502/com.example.android.androidcraftsappprototype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.androidcraftsappprototype, PID: 4502
    android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:468)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
        at com.example.android.androidcraftsappprototype.DBAdapter.getData(DBAdapter.java:86)
        at com.example.android.androidcraftsappprototype.SetupPage$2.onClick(SetupPage.java:118)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: put this method `cursor.moveToFirst();` inside `if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount()>0)`  this condition

Comment: getData() method inside DBHelper and DBHelper not make static. i added my DBHelper class check it

Comment: @HardikVasani Hi! It only bypassed my do-while loop since my cursor is empty. So nothing was put inside the buffer.

Comment: @EllyRichardson if cursor is empty so cursor index value is `-1` so you need to check first cursor count. and cursor.moveToFirst(); there is crash occur bcoz cursor.moveToFirst(); have a no data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your course return 0 item according to query..so you should write below condition

```
 cursor.moveToFirst(); <--- instead of this

 if(cursor.moveToFirst()){

 // here all your code

}
```